# java: JVM parameter -XX:NewRatio seems to not be taking effect

Tags: java, jvm

I have a java application running with following jvm parameters.

```
-XX:+UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=500 -XX:GCTimeRatio=19 
-XX:NewRatio=3 -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseParNewGC  
-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70 -Xmx28g -Xms28g
```

What I am expecting is total NewGen space to be  7GB and OldGen space to be 21GB.
But when I looking at jconsole>java.lang>MemoryPool,

```
NewGen space is around 148MB(Par EdenSpace>Usage>max>139591680 + Par SurviverSpace>Usage>max>17432576) and 
OldGen space is around 27.8GB (CMS OldGen>Usage>max>29890314240)
```

Can some one explain this pls?

**Edit:**
OS   - ubuntu 12.04 64bit
java - 1.6.0_45

Comment: What version of Java are you using? This was a bug in previous versions of Java: http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6862534 (1.4, 5, 6u14)

Comment: Also some JVM distros ignore certain memory settings, EG Excelsior.

Comment: The new ratio is a hint. If you use too much old gen it will ignore your setting.  try `-Xmn7g` if you want a new size of 7 GB

Comment: @mttdbrd: java version is 1.6.0_45

Comment: I don't know that you can use -XX:NewRatio without using the G1 garbage collector. What are you trying to accomplish, or rather, what prompted you to try to play around with memory/GC settings?

Comment: @mttdbrd: its a production environment setting of a project. we are going to work on this project in near future.

Comment: Yes, but why are you fiddling with memory and GC? What problem prompted this? Maybe there's another way to accomplish what you want to accomplish.